# Anchar link on scroll web leads lower than id position

Tags: html, anchor

Anchor link in an "" tag:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
```

Leads to a lower part than I desire:

```
<div id="home">
<!-- Slider Starts -->
<div class="banner">
<div class="caja">
    <div class="videoContainer">
      <div class="imagen-video"></div>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-LRlMcUbDwY?modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&fs=0&loop=1&playlist=-LRlMcUbDwY&rel=0&showinfo=1&disablekb=1&iv_load_policy=0&start=0.8" frameborder="0"></iframe>
          <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-wrapper">
              <div class="caption-info">              
              <h1 class="animated bounceInUp">Dream Nature</h1>
              <p class="animated bounceInLeft">Feel Nature Live Adventures</p>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfSsWDMOtOI&index=4&list=LLZKl8y7fBQ1sCqcdO79S4Rw&t=1s" class="btnfull">Full Video</a>
              <a href="#about" class="explore animated bounceInDown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down  fa-3x"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>    
<!-- </div> -->
<!-- #Slider Ends -->
</div>

<!-- ABOUT US SECTION -->
<div id="about"  class="container-fluid spacer about">
<h2 class="text-center wowload fadeInUp">About Us</h2>  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 wowload fadeInLeft nick">
      <img src="images/nick.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 wowload fadeInRight">
      <h2 class="subheading">Designed by professional , the benefit for creative gigs</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia vel labore, deleniti minima nisi, velit atque quaerat impedit ea maxime sunt accusamus at obcaecati dolor iure iusto omnis quis eum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis commodi odit, illo, qui aliquam dol</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like it to lead to the exact position (height) where the id="about" is located

Now, it just leads to the margin bottom of the first child element ->

```
<h2 class="text-center wowload fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;">About Us</h2>
```

Here is the image of the sections before I click the anchor link:
[image: here the image of the sections before click the anchor link]

Here is the image after clicking:
[image: here image after clicking]

Comment: do you have a a fiddle? or a link to a live page?

Comment: Hi, this is the web project finished and deployed. I got to fix this problem but I had to sacrifice space between sections. So now the real problem is there are too much space in white between sections. @Roysh

Comment: Can you upload a fiddle and explain exactly where would you like to have that white space?

Comment: https://dreamecosafari.com/

Comment: Hi @Roysh. This is the web: https://dreamecosafari.com/ I would like to reduce the white space between sections on the desktop version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jmainol

You have a class called `spacer` which generates this space.

You can go to the css file where it's defined and reduce the space.

Somewhere in  a css file you have this defenition:

```
.spacer {
  padding: 8em 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

You should alter the first line `padding: 8em 0;`. Try to something like `padding: 4em 0;`

**Or**

You can overwrite the definition using a style tag.

```
<style>
     .spacer {
       padding: 4em 0; //you can also try 2em or anything that fits for your
    }
</style>
```

Make sure this tag is inserted after the tage which loads the CSS file (in case that you choose this way)

Answer (score 0):

This https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/wmpXNB maybe what you are looking for.

```
$('#test').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
         $('html, body').animate({
           'scrollTop':   $(href).offset().top + 150
         }, 300);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I discovered something to do it. Its just put for instance a br tag or empty p tag as a element inside the div with the id="about"

```
Here the fiddle: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/38tq8odh/4/embed/"></script>
```

the code of the fiddle example:

```
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="about" class="container-fluid spacer about">In fact Here is the point but without text or anything
<br><br><br><br>
<p>Othertxt point</p>
<br><br><br><br><br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 wowload fadeInLeft nick animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInLeft;">
      <img src="images/nick.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 wowload fadeInRight animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInRight;">
      <h2 class="subheading">Guide you My passion</h2>
      <p>I was born in Arusha and I grew up on the lower slopes of Mount Meru, which is based in Arusha NP. My tribe is Meru, which is the largest tribe in Arusha Region. Because I really love nature, I decided to go to Wildlife College in Kenya. There I got Diploma on wildlife mammals, birds, botany and geography of Tanzania and the national parks.</p>
      <p>In addition I got a driving license for carrying tourists. I have experience as a driver guide in the spectacular Northern parks and southern parks of Tanzania since 2009. I worked with several companies where I gained a lot of experience in tour operating. This made me think of starting my own company. I still do many safaris myself, as I simply love the job.</p>
      <p>My target is not only to bring the tourists in tours and safaris, but also to assist in keeping the environment clean and to do cycling tour as the part of Eco tourism without for get wildlife safaris with our experience safaris guides. This is important, because then we can save nature and keep the existent nature that my country and Africa is proud of. Also, by keeping the environment clean we will be able to continue offering cycling and wildlife safaris in the future.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```